# How to display log4j timestamp in angular brackets

Tags: java, log4j, weblogic

I want to display the timestamp in the log using angular brackets,
  [Jan 21,   2016 13:01:54] should display as  . Below
   is my conversion pattern. I tried to change the  square brackets to 
  angular  but it doesn't display in the right format. I am trying to change
    it  below to match the weblogic log as the weblogic displays it in this
  format. Please assist.

```
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%x [%d{MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss}] 
 [%t]   % -5p [%c] - %m%n"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try \< or \\< or &lt; ?

Comment: I tried with &lt and it worked . Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape `<` by using `&lt;` and `>` by `&gt;` in html or xml based contexts.

Comment: This didn't work for me. In the output, the angle brackets are getting truncated, so the log lines read simply `[%t]   % -5p [%c] - %m%n`